# grpc server reflection using nodejs - Connection not established

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am new to grpc and trying to figure out how to get the service information from grpc servers using reflection. I am using node js with express to get the information.

```
const express = require("express");
const { GrpcReflection } = require('grpc-js-reflection-client');
const process = require('process');
var fs = require('fs');
const grpc =  require('@grpc/grpc-js');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HOST = "grpcb.in:9001";
const HOST1 = "gateway.grpc.com:443";


function getChannelCredentials(){
    return grpc.ChannelCredentials.createSsl();
}

function getServiceList(host){
    console.log("HOST is: " + host);
    try {
        (async()=> {
            const client = new GrpcReflection(
                host, 
                getChannelCredentials(),
                { 
                    "grpc.max_connection_age_ms": 10*1000,
                    'grpc.keepalive_time_ms': 10 * 1000,
                    // Keepalive ping timeout after 5 seconds, default is 20 seconds.
                    'grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms': 5 * 1000,
                    // Allow keepalive pings when there are no gRPC calls.
                    'grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls': 1,
                    "grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 1000,
                }
            );
            console.log(await client.listServices());
        })();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}


app.listen(PORT,() =>{
    console.log("server running on port:", PORT);
    getServiceList(HOST1);
   
});
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "grpc-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample server to get grpc reflection objects using nodejs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "grpc",
    "server-reflection"
  ],
  "author": "pawan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.8.17",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "grpc-js-reflection-client": "^1.2.1",
    "grpc-reflection-js": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  }
}
```

Each time I run node index.js I get

ReflectionRequestException [Error]: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established

Detailed Error:

```
pavenugopal@rws1-venugopal grpc-server % GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=channel,subchannel,call_stream,transport node index.js
server running on port: 3000
HOST is: gateway.grpc.com:443
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.904Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.int.ea.com:443 Channel constructed with options {
  "grpc.max_connection_age_ms": 10000,
  "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 10000,
  "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 5000,
  "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 1,
  "grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 1000
}
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.909Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 createResolvingCall [0] method="/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo", deadline=Infinity
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.911Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.int.ea.com:443 callRefTimer.ref | configSelectionQueue.length=1 pickQueue.length=0
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.957Z | subchannel | (2)  Subchannel constructed with options {
  "grpc.max_connection_age_ms": 10000,
  "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 10000,
  "grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms": 5000,
  "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 1,
  "grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms": 1000
}
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.957Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 callRefTimer.unref | configSelectionQueue.length=1 pickQueue.length=0
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.957Z | subchannel | (2) 159.153.190.73:443 IDLE -> CONNECTING
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.958Z | transport | [object Object] creating HTTP/2 session to 159.153.190.73:443
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.963Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 createRetryingCall [1] method="/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.964Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 createLoadBalancingCall [2] method="/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo"
D 2023-07-14T20:51:50.964Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 callRefTimer.ref | configSelectionQueue.length=0 pickQueue.length=1
D 2023-07-14T20:51:51.181Z | transport | [object Object] connection failed with error 005EF5EC01000000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:ssl/statem/extensions.c:893:

D 2023-07-14T20:51:51.182Z | subchannel | (2) 159.153.190.73:443 CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
D 2023-07-14T20:51:51.182Z | channel | (1) dns:gateway.grpc.com:443 callRefTimer.unref | configSelectionQueue.length=0 pickQueue.length=0
/Users/pavenugopal/Documents/Projects/grpc-server/node_modules/grpc-js-reflection-client/dist/GrpcReflection.js:61
                throw new Exceptions_1.ReflectionRequestException(err);
                ^

ReflectionRequestException [Error]: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
    at ClientDuplexStreamImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/pavenugopal/Documents/Projects/grpc-server/node_modules/grpc-js-reflection-client/dist/GrpcReflection.js:61:23)
    at ClientDuplexStreamImpl.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/pavenugopal/Documents/Projects/grpc-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:419:28)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/pavenugopal/Documents/Projects/grpc-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /Users/pavenugopal/Documents/Projects/grpc-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Node.js v20.4.0
```

But when I try using grpcCurl using the same endpoint I am getting the expected result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Pawan

Comment: It would help to extend the `GRPC_TRACE` option with `transport`, to get more debug information about the connection attempt.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - Added the error with transport in the original message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace log contains this line:

```
D 2023-07-14T20:51:51.181Z | transport | [object Object] connection failed with error 005EF5EC01000000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:ssl/statem/extensions.c:893:
```

The connection is failing due to a TLS problem. Specifically, it looks like the server (or an intervening proxy or firewall) is trying to perform an unsafe legacy renegotiation, and the client is refusing. It may be possible to force the client to do this, but the best solution would be to update whatever software is trying to take this action to conform to current security standards.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work by downgrading my node version from v20 to v16. Now i am able to successfully make the call without any TLS issues.

Answer (score 0):

downgrading my node version from v20 to v16. Now I am able to successfully make the call without any TLS issues.